# What happens when your flag exceeds the character limit?

Tags: support, flags

My flag exceeds the character limit with 2-3 letters.
What will happen to this flag?

Because the comment is marked as flagged but I exceeded the maximum description length.

Comment: Can you see the flag in your flag history?

Comment: Note: moderators can't leave feedback with comment flags, but we dismiss flags like yours as there is *nothing a moderator can do*. We can't tell people to change their opinion about your post or their answer.

Comment: *I click on every link*

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah okay thank you for your anwser.
I was in a bit of a struggle if i should have flagged it or not because it isn't really that big of a deal but i myself still think this is annoying but i am now wondering what your opinion on this is. Did i do good to flag it or didn't i

Comment: @Brynn: you didn't. That's what I was trying to tell you, sorry. Moderators are janitors, basically, we keep the place clean by taking care of actions that the community can't do by themselves. That's about it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you. i will keep my eye out to prevent more of these actions by myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your flag did not exceed the flag length limits and you submitted it without issue. The single comment flag on your account was not too long; there was space for 2 more characters. Perhaps you mistook the *2 characters left* message for the *too long by xxx characters* message that you'd see if your message really was too long?

There is otherwise *no possibility* to submit a flag message that is too long.

The flagging UI prevents you from using text longer than the permitted length. If you can see the 'too long' message, then the submit button remains disabled, so your message would never be truncated:

> [image: bottom of the comment flagging dialog bog with Latin test text in the *something else* flag option textbox, the message *too long by 115 characters* and a greyed-out submit button circled in red with the word *disabled* in red text next to it]

The `Submit` button there is greyed out and disabled. Trying to click on it has no effect. It doesn't matter by how much too long the message is, you can't submit until the message fits the limits.

Even if you were to hack the UI and re-enable the button, the server also refuses to accept messages that are too long, and you'd still get a clear error message (in red):

> [image: same portion of the flagging dialog as before, same test text, but the submit button now obscured by a red rectangular dialog box with the text *Please enter at least 6 and no more than 200 characters*. The red dialog box has a hand-drawn red circle around it]

So if you were able to submit your flag message, then you were also able to keep it within the flag message limits. If anything was cut off, then you would have to have done the cutting before submitting.

You can check your flags by [going to your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current), then clicking on the *helpful flags* link in *impact* box on the right-hand side of your activity summary page.

Comment: I'll use my imagination to make that a free hand red circle ...

Comment: @rene: I tried. I really did. But a freehand red circle around a red box just looked... very, very redundant.

Comment: @rene: I caved. I put it in.

Comment: ROFLOL ... *finds other posts to push Martijn around* ...